# Ubuntu 20 5.4.0-40-generic STUCK on updating Kernel

Tags: boot, kernel, dpkg, raid, mdadm

I'm running Ubuntu 20

We ran apt-get upgrade and its stuck on Upgrading kernel:
Setting up linux-firmware (1.187.3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic

This is "ps af" output:

**1440 pts/0    S+     0:02          _ apt-get upgrade
6839 pts/1    Ss+    0:00              _ /usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 39 --configure --pending
6872 pts/1    S+     0:00                  _ /bin/sh /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-firmware.postinst configure 1.187
6873 pts/1    S+     0:00                      _ /bin/sh /usr/sbin/update-initramfs -u -k all
6886 pts/1    S+     0:00                          _ /bin/sh /usr/sbin/update-initramfs -u -k 5.4.0-40-generic -b /boot
6891 pts/1    S+     0:00                              _ /bin/sh /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs -o /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic.new 5.4.0-40-generic
15649 pts/1    S+     0:00                                  _ /bin/sh /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/mdadm
15764 pts/1    S+     0:00                                      _ /bin/sh /usr/share/mdadm/mkconf
15770 pts/1    D+     0:00                                          _ /sbin/mdadm --examine --scan --config=partitions**

Its waiting for mdadm, any idea why? We do not have any RAIDs on this system.

I found this errors in DMESG:

****[  605.414943] INFO: task mdadm:15770 blocked for more than 241 seconds.
[  605.414963]       Not tainted 5.4.0-40-generic #44-Ubuntu
[  605.414980] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  605.415003] mdadm           D    0 15770  15764 0x00000000
[  605.415004] Call Trace:
[  605.415005]  __schedule+0x2e3/0x740
[  605.415006]  schedule+0x42/0xb0
[  605.415007]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0xe/0x10
[  605.415008]  __mutex_lock.isra.0+0x182/0x4f0
[  605.415009]  ? exact_lock+0x11/0x20
[  605.415010]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
[  605.415011]  __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13/0x20
[  605.415012]  mutex_lock+0x2e/0x40
[  605.415013]  __blkdev_get+0x78/0x550
[  605.415014]  blkdev_get+0x3d/0x140
[  605.415015]  ? blkdev_get_by_dev+0x50/0x50
[  605.415016]  blkdev_open+0x8f/0xa0
[  605.415018]  do_dentry_open+0x143/0x3a0
[  605.415018]  vfs_open+0x2d/0x30
[  605.415020]  do_last+0x194/0x900
[  605.415021]  path_openat+0x8d/0x290
[  605.415025]  ? scsi_device_put+0x2b/0x30
[  605.415026]  do_filp_open+0x91/0x100
[  605.415027]  ? __alloc_fd+0x46/0x150
[  605.415028]  do_sys_open+0x17e/0x290
[  605.415029]  __x64_sys_openat+0x20/0x30
[  605.415031]  do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
[  605.415032]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
[  605.415033] RIP: 0033:0x7f7d2e9faeab
[  605.415034] Code: Bad RIP value.
[  605.415035] RSP: 002b:00007ffede221340 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000101
[  605.415035] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 00007f7d2e9faeab
[  605.415036] RDX: 0000000000004000 RSI: 000055783f062ef0 RDI: 00000000ffffff9c
[  605.415036] RBP: 000055783f062ef0 R08: 1999999999999999 R09: 0000000000000000
[  605.415037] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000004000
[  605.415037] R13: 0000000000004000 R14: 00000000ffffffff R15: 000055783f0665b0**strong text**
[ 1364.028581] kauditd_printk_skb: 24 callbacks suppressed****

Any idea what can cause this?

Comment: Ubuntu 20 implies Ubuntu Core 20 (or another *yy* release), which is a different product to the *yy.mm* format releases like Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Please clarify your release.

Comment: cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS \n \l

5.4.0-40-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 00:01:04 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux